# Question on Avestan Adjectives

Tags: grammar, adjectives, word-order, avestan

Looking at various examples of Avestan, I am confused on how the adjectives work. For instance,

Ahura Mazda, Vohu Manah, Angra Mainyu, Spenta Armaiti, Aka Manah, etc are all adjective first.

But Asha Vahishta, Amesha Spenta, Kshatra Vairya, Azhi Dahāka, etc are adjective last.

So what are the rules for the order in which adjectives go? Like, how would I decide, in a phrase or title, which order to go with? I can't find any source that adequately describes this part of the language.

(also, don't send messages using the Avestan Script, while my phone can process them, my computer doesn't know how to)

Comment: Have you tried applying the word order rules of Greek or Latin?

Comment: @Vegawatcher. What rules?

Comment: I will have to post a larger response, since it is difficult to elaborate in the space of a comment.

Comment: @Vegawatcher. The question was rhetorical.

Answer (score 1):

In Avestan, as in other ancient IE languages, word order is largely free; adjectives can come before their noun, or after it, or separated from it by one or more words.

By the way, Ahura Mazda (or Mazda Ahura, or Ahura ... Mazda) is two nouns ("lord wisdom"), not an adjective plus a noun.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Makes sense why it would be so mixed up if it was free in what end the adjective was placed. That does help me.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may not be what you want, because it does not address Avestan resources specifically.  I offer it just in case it could prove useful for whatever purposes you have.

I don't know much about Avestan specifically, but am presuming it has word order rules that are broadly similar to Sanskrit and Latin, which are also often loosely described as languages with "free" word order.

In their book *Latin Word Order: Structured Meaning and Information*, Devine and Stephens make a very strong case that the word order of Latin, though largely free from a syntactic viewpoint, is actually mostly determined by pragmatic and semantic factors.  They make similar claims in passing about other Indo-European languages, past and present, and analyze Ancient Greek in detail in another book, *Discontinuous Syntax: Hyperbaton in Greek*.  Specific rules will differ from language to language, but they mostly address broad issues.

In Chapter 5 of the first book, they "analyze the order of attributive adjectives (mostly relative to the head) in continuous noun phrases."  They identify multiple factors and even diachronic changes in the word order of certain expressions within Latin.  Nevertheless, some of their conclusions may have a bearing on what your are seeking for Avestan as well.

One conclusion in their book that was particularly illuminating for me was that [intersective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersective_modifier) and [extensional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensional_context%22) adjectives tend to follow their noun heads; whereas non-intersective and intensional adjectives tend to precede them.

Other pragmatic factors can supersede these rules, but they would probably be less applicable to most epithets.  For example, the Latin word *magnus* ("big/large/great") is usually a premodifier, because the objective scale of its meaning depends on what it modifies; for example, a "big" elephant is small compared to a "big" city.  On the other hand, Pompey was called "Pompeius Magnus," matching the word order rules for cognomens (roughly, nicknames) and perhaps also suggesting a more extentional meaning of *magnus*, i.e. someone comparable to all great things, rather than just a great for a man or great as a leader.

Another very general principle I got from Devine and Stephens' book is that the pragmatically more important word tends to come first.  The application of this rule depends, obviously, on what the pragmatic goal of the expression is.

When I apply what I think I understand of these Latin rules to the Avestan names you listed, here are some tentative explanations I would propose for your consideration.  I am guessing at the translations based on quick internet searches and leave the specifics to your expertise.

Ahura Mazda (Lord Wisdom):

Putting "Ahura" first may be pragmatically more important in identifying the reference of the combination.  It also seems to have an intensional focus on enhancing respect rather than an extensional focus on classifying what type of "wisdom" is meant.  It actually seems to modify his status form a semantic point of view rather than the word "wisdom" itself.  In other words, it expresses something more like "lordly wisdom" than "wisdom of a lordly type."

Vohu Manah (Good Mind), Angra Mainyu (Evil Spirit), and Akah Manah (Bad Mind):

"Good," "Evil," and "Bad" may be used here as intensional and emotive words whose semantic range depends on their nouns and so maybe should be premodifiers in this case.  Their meaning is subjective and presupposes a modification of aspects of their nouns, rather than the entire nouns themselves.  They presuppose underlying "arguments" or aspects of the noun they modify.

Spenta Armaiti (Holy Devotion):

The adjective here is perhaps again intensional and meant to enhance the picture of devotion, rather than extensional and meant to subclassify a type of "devotion."

Asha Vahishta (Best Truth):

Here the postmodification may be intended to express an extensional meaning, i.e., not just any truth, but the best of all, "the truth that is the best," rather than an intensional meaning like "a most excellent truth."

Amesha Spenta (Holy Immortal):

I am not sure which is the head in this case.  If it is *Spenta*, than perhaps *Amesha* is used intensionally to enhance the picture of a holy/bountiful one, rather than extensionally to subclassify holy/bountiful ones between mortal and immortal ones.  If the head is *Amesha*, perhaps *Spenta* is used extensionally to distinguish between immortals worthy of devotion and those who are not.

Kshatra Vairya (Desirable Dominion):

Here Vairya seems to be extensional and simply refers to all things desirable, not some aspect of Kshatra that is desirable.

Azhi Dahāka (? Snake):

I can't find a reliable meaning for Azhi Dahāka and so cannot really guess at the logic of its ordering.  Maybe it refers to a type of snake, and therefore Dahāka is viewed extensionally to indicate its "species."

Comment: That would make sense, yeah, free word order that just works with what is most important in the name. And on Azhi Dahaka, I know Azhi means serpent, and found on a site of Avestan vocabulary that Dahaka means stinging.

Comment: I should also make clear that although I could often talk about these differences as "nuances," they can affect truth conditions.  For instance, "asking for responsible people" implies you think they are competent, but "asking for the people responsible" might imply the opposite in a specific case.  Especially when talking about philosophical or theological concepts, I think word order often does reflect different assertions about what is being described.